# Trouble running a Python script through VB

Tags: python, vb.net, opencv, web-applications

The objective is to receive an image path and pass that to a Python program as an argument, then receive the results.

This is done through a web app using VB (on the IIS server) and it works perfectly **except** when I import the python module OpenCV (imported in Python as `cv2`, more specifically).

What's even more confusing is that the script runs perfectly with the imported `cv2` module when executed directly from cmd. It only fails to work when the VB code runs the script including the line `import cv2`.

I'll show some code below, for clarity.

**VB code running Python script with image path as an argument:**

```vb
Dim Processtask As New System.Diagnostics.Process()
Processtask.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
Processtask.StartInfo.Arguments = "/c python " + path.ToString + " " + ImageURL.ToString
Processtask.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
Processtask.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
Processtask.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
Processtask.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
Processtask.Start()
Processtask.WaitForExit()
output = Processtask.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd()
```

**Python code snippet receiving image path:**

```
import sys
import cv2
if __name__ == "__main__":
    im = str(sys.argv[1])
print(im)
```

I have run out of possible ideas as to what could cause this problem. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

I managed to find the full error message which reads as follows:

```
System.Exception: System.IO.StreamReader
System.InvalidOperationException: Process has exited, so the requested 
information is not available. 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.EnsureState(State state) at 
System.Diagnostics.Process.get_ProcessName() 
at System.Diagnostics.Process.ToString()
```

Comment: Does the environment (global or venv) VB is using have (correct) cv2 library installed. I.e. does the Python code run in command line, too.

Comment: Yes, the cv2 library is installed in the same environment. The Python script runs without issues from command prompt as well as in Spyder.

Comment: as you mention it "crashes" please update your question with the full traceback from python

Comment: Since the code is run through the web app, there is no Python traceback. It simply returns "System.Exception: 1". When the Python script is run in Spyder there are no issues.

Comment: as you code "run through the web app" I would suggest you debug your web app.

Comment: Also, you may want to capture [Processtask.StandardError](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standarderror(v=vs.110).aspx) as your error could be there

Comment: I managed to redirect the output for a full readout. I've updated the post with the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution eventually, I'll post it here in case anyone else ever runs into this problem:

The dll files of opencv installed onto the server which hosted the web app had different access rights. The files were denied access when being called from the web application, whereas the rest of the modules called had no issue.

I used [sysinternals process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to trace which files were being denied access and was able to change the rights by hand. Not very elegant but it worked out.